# How do i solve field error for querying my model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'username_contains' into field. Choices are: bio, id, username
```

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def endpoints_list(request):

    query=request.GET.get('query')
    if query == None:
        query=''

    print(query)
    adv_data=Advocate.objects.filter(username_contains=query)
    serializer=AdvocateSerializer(adv_data,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I tried querying model but it says it cannot convert it into field

Comment: Your lookups should be separated by a double-underscore - `Advocate.objects.filter(username__contains=query)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a double undersocre __

```
adv_data=Advocate.objects.filter(username__contains=query)
```